# Wix 32-bit and 64-bit MSIs not uninstalling each other

Tags: .net, wix, x86, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

We currently ship a 32-bit .NET application. Our next version has a 64-bit and 32-bit MSI built from the same WIX project file using the standard tricks found here on SO.

If I upgrade v1 (32-bit) to v2 (64-bit), the Wix will uninstall the old version (from Program Files (x86)) and put v2 in Program Files. Exactly what I wanted.

If I then try to install the 32-bit version of v2, it will install the 32-bit version alongside the 64-bit version of v2, and both are present in their respective Program Files and Program Files (x86) folder.

If I then re-run the 64-bit MSI for v2, it will correctly uninstall the 32-bit version and install only the 64-bit version.

My product codes are dynamically generated and both MSIs have the same `UpgradeCode`.

```
<Product Id="*" Name="Awesome Product" Language="1033" Version="$(var.Version)" 
         Manufacturer="Company, Inc." UpgradeCode="C7F99857-9999-4D36-AAA2-34B1D364BE19">
```

The log files don't look that different but what I do see in the 64-to-32 bit version, which is the one that doesn't work as expected and does not uninstall the 64-bit software:

> PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ProgramFiles64Folder property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files\'. Its new value: 'c:\Program Files (x86)\'.

This happens some time after the message:

> Doing action: RemoveExistingProducts

So I'm wondering if it is somehow updating the path that it will be using to uninstall packages and therefore not actually removing anything?

I feel like I've searched and read every related web page, blog post and mailing list message, but I'm open to any suggestions and references.

EDIT: I checked the log for the 32->64 bit upgrade for FindRelatedProducts. In that file I see:

```
Action start 14:53:55: INSTALL.
MSI (c) (24:B4) [14:53:55:392]: UI Sequence table 'InstallUISequence' is present and populated.
MSI (c) (24:B4) [14:53:55:392]: Running UISequence
MSI (c) (24:B4) [14:53:55:392]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding EXECUTEACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
MSI (c) (24:B4) [14:53:55:392]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
MSI (c) (24:B4) [14:53:55:392]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action 14:53:55: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 14:53:55: FindRelatedProducts.
FindRelatedProducts: Found application: {85A5CC9D-3C1C-403D-B539-CA95B77B49ED}
MSI (c) (24:B4) [14:53:55:392]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OLDPRODUCTFOUND property. Its value is '{85A5CC9D-3C1C-403D-B539-CA95B77B49ED}'.
Action ended 14:53:55: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
```

Then when I install the 32-bit version on top of the 64-bit version:

```
Action 15:02:37: INSTALL. 
Action start 15:02:37: INSTALL.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [15:02:37:421]: UI Sequence table 'InstallUISequence' is present and populated.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [15:02:37:421]: Running UISequence
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [15:02:37:421]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding EXECUTEACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [15:02:37:421]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [15:02:37:421]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action 15:02:37: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 15:02:37: FindRelatedProducts.
FindRelatedProducts: Found application: {3AF0BDBB-6F3B-4A2C-B8EC-42FB970A7C44}
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [15:02:37:422]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OLDPRODUCTFOUND property. Its value is '{3AF0BDBB-6F3B-4A2C-B8EC-42FB970A7C44}'.
Action ended 15:02:37: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
```

Comment: In a 32-bit installation, the property change you mention is normal. Are your two installations removing the other one via Upgrade table entries? If so, are the opposite-bitness ones found in both cases? Look in the log near `FindRelatedProducts`.

Comment: @MichaelUrman yep, it appears as though both the 32->64 install and the 64->32 install find the related products. I'm updating the question with the notes.

Answer (score 0):

FindRelatedProducts may find something, but that doesn't mean that it will do the upgrade. The rest of the log would show this, but if you have OnlyDetect set Yes in an upgrade element in your x86 setup then it won't upgrade, just an example of what might be wrong. Or you don't have a RemoveExistingProducts action or it's conditioned or something.

It's also possible, though perhaps unlikely, that your RemoveExistingProducts is after InstallFinalize (or otherwise outside the transaction) then if the x64 uninstall fails (for example after InstallFinalize) then it will roll back and leave both products installed.